# What is the best way to show large MYSQL result into table with search/pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phalcon

I have over 200.000 results inside a table with 20 columns (62MB). I want to show them in an HTML table.
I ever did it with DataTables, but now it takes very long to load or not loading.
My application is done with Phalcon/PHP with this call:

```
$catalog = Catalog::find();

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        {% for item in catalog %}
        <tr class="odd">                     
          <td class="pointer hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{ item.description }}</td>
          <td class="pointer hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{ item.description2 }}</td>
          <td class="pointer hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{ item.description3 }}</td> 
          <td class="pointer hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{ item.description4 }}</td>
          <td class="pointer hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{ item.description5 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

The table is just an example not the real one with 20 cols. The question is: do you recommend using any plugin to avoid loading all data into the table, or specific solution? It must be fast and responsive, and being able to search by columns like datatables.

Comment: try using custom datatable with query at backend using limit.

Comment: Why not continue using DataTables, but use the Ajax method? Docs: https://datatables.net/manual/ajax#Loading-data

Comment: I looked at this: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html
But it required ssp.class.php and lot of stuff that is not MVC like

Comment: @NikolayMihaylow is not too much data to keep in a json?

Comment: Sergio: server side script is just an example. In your Controller you fetch data and return it as json. @M.I. no its not much data for json, because he will only output one page at a time, not the whole 200k results.

Comment: @Sergio i think this is not limited by the database querry itself, but to show  a table with 200.000 rows in a browser window it may be too much. 
Make a querry with limit and create multiple pages, execute the querry for each page, like 50 result/page should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it with datatables server side with great results. Thaks everyone